# How to determine if variable is simplexmlelement, an is_simplexmlelement function?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, simplexml, warnings

I am getting all types of warnings in a loop first:

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

<b>Warning</b>:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 2: parser error : Premature end of data in tag imageThumb2Url line 2 in <b>/var/www/category_search.php</b> on line <b>49</b><br />
```

It breaks at some points, likely of a timeout in the connection on the other side or something.

Then I have a function that expects a simplexmlelement as its input:

```
function XML2Array(SimpleXMLElement $parent)
{
//rest of function
}
```

So the loops gets broken when after generating those warnings I try to make use of the function with this error:

```
<b>Catchable fatal error</b>:  Argument 1 passed to XML2Array() must be an instance of SimpleXMLElement, boolean given
```

I would like to dertermine before trying to use the function whether I'm about to send a simplexmlelement or not, in such case use a continue in the loop.

Comment: show the actual code that is causing the error

Comment: Are you calling source to SimpleXMLElement?
For example:

"use ProjectFiles\App\SimpleXMLElement" -
Above your function XML2Array

Comment: Would doing `    $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

    if($xml){$results=XML2Array($xml);}` be helpful ?